# How to add column name in single string?

Tags: python, postgresql, dbt

I have a code where I'm flattening the jsonb columns so I have written a code something like this

```
{% set survey_methods_query %}

SELECT DISTINCT(jsonb_object_keys(_airbyte_data)) as column_name 
from {{source('survey-cto', 'raw_surveycto')}}
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(survey_methods_query) %}

{% if execute %}
{# Return the first column #}
{% set results_list = results.columns[0].values() %}
{% else %}
{% set results_list = [] %}
{% endif %}

select
_airbyte_data,
{% for column_name in results_list %}
_airbyte_data->>{{ column_name }} as {{ column_name }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
from {{source('survey-cto', 'raw_surveycto')}}
```

So when you compile the dbt then its giving me a structure like this

```
select
_airbyte_data,

_airbyte_data->>simid as simid,

_airbyte_data->>lease_season_None as lease_season_None,
```

So I'm getting this error because the column name is not in single string. How do I deal with this?

```
 column "simid" does not exist
08:29:11    LINE 23: _airbyte_data->>simid as simid,
```

the airbyte data looks like this

```
{"KEY": "59dcc7la-4222-46ba-83a5-f59a5f78d656", "shg": "0", "didi": "G (non-official)", "loan": "0", "simid": "89918560200035541720", "aadhar": "1", "caseid": "", "endtime": "Mar 30, 2022 11:12:30 AM", "form_id": "baseline_ig ", "hh_size": "5", "savings": "0", "bank_acc": "0"}
```

Comment: Please specify which RDMS you're using e.g. snowflake/BigQuery/redshift and an example of the JSON in `_airbyte_data`

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using postgres and _airbyte_data is a jsonb column

Comment: No problem, please add the `postgres` tag to your post, and it would be helpful if you can add a few of the _airbyte_data rows to your question so we can see the structure of it e.g. `{ simid: blah, lease_season_None: 123 }`

Comment: So basically I'm not able to query the data if the column name is not in single quotes. I have added the data how it looks like

Comment: Ah I see, so you can change your Jinja to `_airbyte_data->>'{{ column_name }}' as {{ column_name }}` where there are single quotes around the column name. Or update your query to include the single quotes `SELECT concat('''', DISTINCT(jsonb_object_keys(_airbyte_data)), '''') as column_name`

Comment: Great this what I wanted. Do you want to put your solution below. So I can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON field names need to be wrapped in single quotes to be selected in postgresql so you can change your Jinja to have single quotes around the column name.

`_airbyte_data->>'{{ column_name }}' as {{ column_name }}`

Or update your query to include the single quotes in the initial SELECT

`SELECT concat('''', DISTINCT(jsonb_object_keys(_airbyte_data)), '''') as column_name`